# How to trigger a POST event automatically for Google Charts and iTextSharp?

Tags: google-visualization, itext

I am currently writing code to transfer Google Chart images into PDF using the iTextSharp library.

I am using GET requests for each chart, so that each chart is an img with a src that uses "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x100& [parameter 1] [parameter 2]...[parameter n]"

I would like to use POST requests so that I can pass more chart parameters, but I do not know how to trigger a post request because iTextSharp will not execute any JavaScript on the page before converting it to PDF

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: See the documentation for [POST requests with the Image Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/post_requests).

Comment: Yes I did before I posted the question.   The problem with that document is that you must click a button to trigger the post request.  This is not a viable solution since I am producing a PDF document that will not be exposed to JavaScript code or user-triggered, client side events.  I need the post to execute automatically as the page is being converted by iTextSharp

Comment: If you're server-side then just use a `System.Net.WebClient` and call one of the [`UploadXYZ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) methods like [`UploadValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does iTextSharp execute javascript?  If it does, then you can trigger the form submission with javascript.

Comment: I'm new to using iTextSharp.  Basically any document you send to it will, by default, not have JS executed on it.  There may be a way to do so but, if there is, I don't know it!

Comment: There's two parts to JavaScript in this context that need to be understood. One is PDF JavaScript and the other is web-based JavaScript. PDF JavaScript is intended for a renderer such as Adobe Reader to execute. iTextSharp can **write** this JavaScript but since it is not a PDF renderer is won't execute this JavaScript. Web-based JavaScript doesn't exist in PDF and therefore doesn't exist in iTextSharp. The example you posted _happens_ to use JavaScript to make things easier for users to control the chart. Below that is the server-side version that you'll need to translate from PHP to .Net.